# htaccess rewriterule internally redirect not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my url internally from

https://url/file/value to https://url/file/original_script.php?get=$1

where value is equal to $1 but when I go to https://url/file/value it redirects me to the second url (rewrites browser url)

My htaccess code looks like these:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ /file/original_script.php?get=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: Is it possible you've experimented with `R=permanent` and your browser has just cached it? Can you try with a different browser or value?

Comment: I haven't use that rule and I've tried with different browsers and no success either...but thanks for your suggestion! @WouterHuysentruit

Comment: I just copied the snippet in a apache2 vhost config and it works perfectly, if you show us the whole .htaccess we might find the issue

Comment: @PhilippWrann I had it written before this piece of code:    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>    maybe this is the problem (?)

Comment: Do you have .htaccess inside `file/` directory?

Comment: Still working like you expect it, like @anubhava suggested, do you have a separat .htaccess within the file directory?

Comment: @PhilippWrann yes. My .htaccess is placed on root directory not on     file/